# How can I bundle Typescript AppSync resolvers in the CDK?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

AppSync GraphQL resolvers can be [written in JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-js-version.html) instead of VTL. AppSync has dev-time helpers for [TypeScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-overview-js.html#additional-utilities) resolvers, but we must bundle the code ourselves.

How can I bundle `.ts` resolvers in the CDK?

We pass the resolver code to the CDK [AppsyncFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.AppsyncFunction.html) construct. But we can't directly pass a `my-resolver.ts` file. Instead, `appsync.Code.fromAsset` needs `my-resolver.js`. Right now there isn't a batteries-included `esbuild` local bundling option like the one NodejsLambda construct [has](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#local-bundling).

```js
const resolverFunc = new appsync.AppsyncFunction(this, "MyResolverFunc", {
  name: "my_resolver",
  api,
  dataSource: dynamoDataSource,
  code: appsync.Code.fromAsset(
    path.join(__dirname, "../path/to/my_resolver.ts") // <- ❌ need a .js file here
  ),
  runtime: appsync.FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, a `esbuild` script run during the CDK synth process seems the simplest option.

**[Step 1]**  Add a `esbuild` script to `package.json`.  The bundling script, presented below in non-stringified form for clarity, outputs one `.mjs` file for each `.ts` resolver input file.  The settings follow the example in the AppSync [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-reference-overview-js.html#additional-utilities):

```bash
esbuild path/to/resolvers/*.ts \
  --bundle \
  --sourcemap=inline \                  # optional
  --sources-content=false \             # optional, but recommended with sourcemaps
  --platform=node \
  --target=esnext \
  --format=esm \
  --external:@aws-appsync/utils \
  --out-extension:.js=.mjs \            # optional, output files with the esm .mjs extension
  --outdir=dist                         # where to put the bundled .js artefacts
```

**[Step 2]** Tell the CDK to use the script with the build arg in the command line (`cdk synth --build myBundleScript`) or in `cdk.json` config file (`build: myBundleScript`).

**[Step 3]** Finally, point the AppsyncFunction construct's `code` prop to an asset built from the Javascript:

```js
const func = new appsync.AppsyncFunction(this, "MyResolverFunc", {
   name: "my_resolver",
   api,
   dataSource,
   code: appsync.Code.fromAsset("dist/my_resolver.mjs"), // ✅
   runtime: appsync.FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
});
```

Alternatives?  There is currently no built-in CDK bundler for AppSync resolvers.  The NodejsLambda bundler seems like it would work, but it is not an exported member.  Finally, while the AssetStaging construct has [bundling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.AssetStaging.html#bundling) options, it only emits a `.zip` archive, rather than the `.js` or `.mjs` file that AppSync is looking for (see GitHub [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/24548)).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what @fedonev said it's also possible to do this completely inside of CDK, without the need of "external" esbuild.

You can use CDK's feature to bundle assets in a docker container. What you basically do is execute the TypeScript transpilation, eslint, tests, esbuild inside of a docker container and pass the container's output files back to CDK.

Something along the lines of:

```
api.createResolver('GetTodoResolver', {
            typeName: 'Query',
            fieldName: 'getTodo',
            runtime: appsync.FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
            code: appsync.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'resolvers'), {
                bundling: {
                    outputType: BundlingOutput.SINGLE_FILE,
                    image: DockerImage.fromRegistry('public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:18.18.0-slim'),
                    environment: {
                        NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX: '/tmp/.npm-global',
                        NPM_CONFIG_CACHE: '/tmp/.npm-cache',                            
                    },
                    command: ['bash', '-c', ['npm install', 'npm run dist', 'cp dist/appsync/* /asset-output',].join(' && '),],
                    
                }
            }),
          dataSource: noneDS
        });
```

There's also a blog post available which describes the bundling approach in more detail: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-apps-with-aws-cdk/

Comment: Hello! I was able to implement this solution. Then I upgraded my cdk cli to `2.106.1` and now I am getting this error `npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /tmp/.npm-cache
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/.npm-cache'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent`. I already tried to `rm -fr node_modules package-lock` and `npm i`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tested above code with cdk 2.110.0 and it still worked for me. Are you using a different `image`? You could try to create the directories from the `command` array before `npm install`. Adding `mkdir -p $NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` and `mkdir -p $NPM_CONFIG_CACHE`?

Comment: I uploaded my example to github: https://github.com/jwoehrle/cdk-appsync-resolver-examples

Comment: I am using the same image as you. If I bundle beforehand and synth with `code: appsync.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/resolver.ts'))` it works. And with the same bundling config as you, with the correct path, I get the error above. Adding `mkdir` I get `mkdir: cannot create directory '/tmp/.npm-global': No space left on device`. I did some cleanup `docker system prune` and relaunched with `mkdir` and it is all good. Removed `mkdir` (i.e. same bundling as you) all good. Thanks